# How to record Auto suggestion filed in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

As i am new to use Selenium IDE. I am facing a problem i.e.

There is a filed named skills which automatically gives suggestion when we type any text in text area. and the problem is i am not able to record this  section. as i tried manually also like below.

For 1st image : when i give input through keyboard without recording than it's give me suggestion like this image

http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1z2lFAx11KOlXRxHO3dZ6tH7rw6bxu0

For 2nd image : But when i recorded it and when i play this script than it's not giving me suggestion

http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1aschc5kYc9YE3YqtqzAS03zXSXIp

I tried with this code but it's not helpful for me.....can anyone please suggest me how to record it.

and one more problem is skills id is dynamic which changes every time.

Can anyone tells also how to give input at run time in selenium IDE.

```
click id=skillAutocomplete

type id=skillAutocomplete cakephp

waitForTextPresent CakePHP

mouseOver //html/body/ul[2]/li/a CakePHP

click //html/body/ul[2]/li/a CakePHP
```

Comment: you may need to add a "waitFor" after you type for the page to have time to load the new information before you check for it.

Comment: Also, there may be a javascript event that's not being triggered on the field that you may have to fire manually. Check "FireEvent"

Comment: Thanks DMart For your reply.......

Comment: I have found the solution for it and that is instead of to use above path we can also use XPath like "^[\\s\\S]*CakePHP[\\s\\S]*$" or Xpath like "//(contains(text())"......this path is recorded at a time of recording script we just need to select it from the drop down of the commands......